# Change default post style to columns

Tags: posts, theme-development, customization, columns

I'm trying to format each post that the user uploads.

I need the paragraphs to be floated to the left in the first column, and the images to be in a floated left in the second column.

(I've tried posting an image, but I need at least 10 reputation)

I am new to Wordpress development, so I apologise if this is a silly question.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways to that but what I like to do is to create shortcodes e.g [one_half] :

```
function one_half_sh( $atts, $content = null ) {
return '<div class="one-half">' . do_shortcode($content) . '</div>';
}
add_shortcode( 'one_half', 'one_half_sh' );
```

Then the CSS can look like this :

```
.one-half {
width: 48%;
margin: 0 4% 0 0;
float: left;
}
```

The second column would have the same markup but with  0 margin. 
This allows to set a very flexible layout you can customize on each post.

**EDIT:** for the second column just create another shortcode with exactly the same code but add a CSS class such as `.second-col` you will style in your stylesheet

Comment: Thanks. Where abouts would the function be placed— where within index.php?

Comment: no within `functions.php` of the current theme